# ASP.NET MVC 5. How to turn off autologin after registration

Tags: autologin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need to turn off automatic login after registration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found 
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

line in my code and just commented it. Thats solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a line on the code that goes like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, False)
```

Comment it or change False to True.